# Hadoop: JobTracker eating... 300% CPU?

Tags: linux, hadoop

Recently, Ganglia displays almost Hadoop servers in red color.

[image]

Looking through the `atop`, `htop`, ... I see that the `jobtracker` and `namenode` process is eating ~300% CPU:

```
30858  adtech    adtech      42   15.54s    13.17s      0K      0K      0K      0K   --    -  S      6  332%   java
31066  adtech    adtech      24    6.18s     8.86s      0K      0K      0K      0K   --    -  S      7  174%   java
31164  adtech    adtech      44    5.66s     8.38s      0K      0K      0K      4K   --    -  S      5  162%   java
```

Here're the related configuration files:

**core-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
   <property>
       <name>fs.default.name</name>
       <value>hdfs://hmaster90:9000</value>
       <description>
       The name of the default file system. Either the literal string
       "local" or a host:port for NDFS.
       </description>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>

   <property>
     <name>dfs.replication</name>
     <value>2</value>
   </property>

   <property>
     <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
     <value>/data/hdfs11/dfs/name</value>
   </property>

   <property>
     <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
     <value>/data/hdfs11/dfs/data</value>
   </property>

   <property>
     <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
     <value>/data/hdfs11/dfs/tmp</value>
   </property>

</configuration>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>

    <property>
      <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
      <value>hmaster90:9001</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>mapred.system.dir</name>
      <value>/data/hdfs11/mapreduce/system</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>mapred.local.dir</name>
      <value>/data/hdfs11/mapreduce/local</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>mapred.temp.dir</name>
      <value>/data/hdfs11/mapreduce/temp</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name>
      <value>7</value>
      <description>
            The maximum number of map tasks that will be run simultaneously by a task tracker.
      </description>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum</name>
      <value>7</value>
      <description>
            The maximum number of reduce tasks that will be run simultaneously by a task tracker.
      </description>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>mapred.map.tasks</name>
      <value>56</value>
      <description>
        This should be a prime number larger than multiple number of slave hosts,
        e.g. for 3 nodes set this to 17
      </description>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>mapred.reduce.tasks</name>
      <value>21</value>
      <description>
        This should be a prime number close to a low multiple of slave hosts,
        e.g. for 3 nodes set this to 7
      </description>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

**jobtracker.log**: https://gist.github.com/3032037

Where should I take a look at first?

---

**Reply to @J-16SDiZ:**

```
# su - adtech
$ jstack -J-d64 -m 3135
Attaching to process ID 3135, please wait...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.runJStackTool(JStack.java:136)
    at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.main(JStack.java:102)
Caused by: sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VMVersionMismatchException: Supported versions are 14.0-b16. Target VM is 20.5-b03
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VM.checkVMVersion(VM.java:223)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VM.<init>(VM.java:286)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VM.initialize(VM.java:344)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.bugspot.BugSpotAgent.setupVM(BugSpotAgent.java:594)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.bugspot.BugSpotAgent.go(BugSpotAgent.java:494)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.bugspot.BugSpotAgent.attach(BugSpotAgent.java:332)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:163)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.main(JStack.java:86)
```

Comment: see http://superuser.com/questions/174660/why-is-the-cpu-usage-reported-by-top-in-linux-over-100

Comment: I know that. I'm asking that what causes jobtracker use almost CPU recently while it only uses ~ 20% before (no new jobs).

Comment: dump a stackstace first. `kill -3 <pid>` or `jstack <pid>`.

Comment: Could it be the revenge of the leap second?

Comment: @J-16SDiZ: `jstack -J-d64 -m 1741
Attaching to process ID 1741, please wait...
Error attaching to process: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach to the process`

Comment: your `jstack` run failed (because your jstack/java version don't match). This give no stacktrace on your problem.q

Comment: Looks like a GC or swapping problem to me, can you provide additional data on that? heap usages etc?

Comment: @wildplasser: maybe, because it goes away after my co-workder rebooting. Is there any signals to confirm it? I don't see any error related to ntpd in `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: Well, it was related to spinlocks and futexes spinning. I don't think that spinning locks write anything to syslog. http://serverfault.com/q/403732